# ProGuard build failed on Android with OpenCSV dependency

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard, opencsv

I have a dependency on OpenCSV 3.8 and release build fails with ProGuard error:

> Warning:org.apache.commons.beanutils.MappedPropertyDescriptor: can't find referenced method 'void setName(java.lang.String)' in program class org.apache.commons.beanutils.MappedPropertyDescriptor

I can try to ignore it but it does not sound good fix.

Interesting that OpenCSV 3.8 depends on commons-beanutils 1.9.3 while locally installed 1.9.2.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Peter4499 how to fix build error without ignoring it.

Comment: @4ybaka Have you found any workaround?

Comment: @Dharmendra no, I just ignored warnings

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issue with openCSV:3.9, it was showing some warnings in debug build and it was throwing errors while build with proguard.

To fix this problem I done below changes and now I am able to build apk

In module level build.gradle add below line

```
configurations {
     all*.exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
}
```

In the proguard file

```
-dontwarn com.opencsv.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.beanutils.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.collections.**
-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature,InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod
-dontoptimize
```

Hope this will help for you and other who are facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below rules for `apache comms` in your progaurd file:

```
-keep class org.apache.commons.** { *; }
```

Progaurd will use above rule and do not obfuscate classes contained in package `org.apache.commons` so you can use it.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Build fails with the same error.